# Overloaded << operator for a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, g++, overloading

I am getting a very strange error even when the << operator is overloaded for the below map, Feature.h is used by a class named Session.C and I am trying to print the values of the map tKeyboard using <<. I am new to all this and this being a very old code I am baffled about the issue, can you folks suggest some thing. 
Appreciate it thanks.

Feature.h

```
class Feature {
..
public:

 typedef map<string,KeyStroke,std::less<string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const string, KeyStroke> > > tKeyboard;
                               // It is a map of keys
                               // key is the name of the keystroke
      typedef  tKeyboard::const_iterator cKeysIter;
      typedef  tKeyboard::iterator KeysIter;
..
  private:
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,const tKeyboard &);
..
};
```

Feature.C

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,const Feature::tKeyboard &k)
{
    os <<" Keyboard >\n";
    for (Feature::cKeysIter i=k.begin() ; i!= k.end() ; i++)
    {
        os << "key name:"<<(*i).first << " ="<< (*i).second ;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Session.C

```
 if (keyStrokeVal.empty()){
       Traced(3)<<"sendKey:Error, key "<<keyname<<" not defined or empty\n";
       Traced(7)<<"Printing Feature "<<mCurrentFeature->get_mName() <<" 's keyboard \n" << mCurrentFeature->get_mKeyboard();
       Traced(7)<<"\n";
       return(-1);
    }
```

Error:

```
Session.C:541: error: no match for âoperator<<â in âstd::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)std::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)((std::ostream*)LogMgr::traceRovr())->std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](std::endl [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]))), ((const char*)"Session.C")))), ((const char*)" ")))->std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](541))), ((const char*)" - ")))->std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](out_time))), ((const char*)"Printing Feature ")))), ((const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)((const std::string*)((Session*)this)->Session::mCurrentFeature->Feature::get_mName()))))), ((const char*)" \'s keyboard \012")) << ((Session*)this)->Session::mCurrentFeature->Feature::get_mKeyboard()â
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:117: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:127: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:165: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:91: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:180: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:105: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:191: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:200: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:209: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:221: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:119: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

Comment: Does it work if you stream to `std::cout` instead of `Traced`?

Comment: The error is about `operator<<`, but the offending line has 4 of them. Can you isolate the problem?

Comment: I strongly believe a `friend` declaration (not definition) of a function does not actually introduce the function name into the surrounding scope, but I can't find a quote in the standard for that now. Can you try repeating the declaration outside the class?

Comment: @Angew: "The name of a function first introduced in a friend declaration is in the scope of the first nonclass scope that contains the enclosing class."

Comment: @MSalters Can you provide the section & paragraph as well? A full text search in the standard didn't find your quote (could just be a PDF problem).

Comment: @Angew: That was from IBM documentation, not a standard quote. But it's short and clear.

Comment: @Angew I can confirm gcc 4.7.3 agrees with the IBM quote.

Comment: @MSalters It seems to me [namespace.memdef]§3 contradicts this (see my answer).

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but why are you specifying all of the default arguments when you declare the map type?  (Particularly the allocator, which will probably just confuse most readers.)

Comment: @MSalters There's a very subtle issue involved.  The friend declaration does declare the operator in the surrounding namespace, but it doesn't make it visible there.  In such cases, the operator (or function) can only be found by ADL.  Most of the time, this is fine, since one of the arguments will have the type `Feature`; in this case, it doesn't work, because the types of the parameters only involves `std` and the class `KeyStroke`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if a `friend` declaration first declares (but does not define) a function, that function's name is not introduced into the surrounding scope. Quoting C++11, [namespace.memdef]§3:

> If a `friend` declaration in a nonlocal class first declares a class or function the friend class or function is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. **The name of the friend is not found by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or by qualified lookup (3.4.3) until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope** (either before or after the class definition granting friendship). If a friend function is called, its name may be found by the name lookup that considers functions from namespaces and classes associated with the types of the function arguments (3.4.2).

(Emphasis mine)

The solution is therefore a separate out-of-class declaration:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os,const Feature::tKeyboard &);
```

Comment: Yup, that bold part is also a possible reason for the problem. Not sure about the "introduced" part, though. The `friend` declaration declares a function, and each function exists in precisely one namespace.

Comment: @MSalters That was just my informal statement. Basically, while the function is in the namespace, its name is not accessible in there (yet). That's how I understand it.

Comment: @Angew That's more or less right.  The name _is_ in the global namespace; i.e. the fully qualified name would be `::operator<<(...)`.  It isn't visible there, however; visibility is a separate issue from where the symbol resides.  (And I'll admit that it is a subtle and confusing issue.)

Comment: @Angew and @MSalters, Thank you for your response, I get the following error if I add that line in Feature.h `error: expected unqualified-id before â&â token`

Comment: This did solve my issue, it is just that the declaration should be after the class declaration. Thank you folks for helping me out...

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is that your `::operator<<` is not found because the global namespace isn't searched. And you're not allowed to add your `operator<<` to `::std::`. If this is the case, it can be fixed with a local `using ::operator<<`.

Comment: The global namespace is searched.  But the name isn't visible in the global namespace at this point; it can only be seen by ADL, and only then if one of the arguments involves `Feature` in some way.  (Note too if you're an old hand with C++.  This is a change from pre-standard C++, where the friend statement not only declared the function in the surrounding namespace, but injected the name there as well.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: We only see part of `Session.C`, so I'm not sure that code is actually in the global namespace itself. But you're right: even if it was searched, the name isn't visible.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried adding the output operator to namespace std to help ADL?

```
namespace std{
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,const Feature::tKeyboard &k)
{
  os <<" Keyboard >\n";
  for (Feature::cKeysIter i=k.begin() ; i!= k.end() ; i++)
  {
    os << "key name:"<<(*i).first << " ="<< (*i).second ;
  }
  return os;
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `friend` function is `::operator<<`, and not `::std::operator<<`.  So you've defined a different function.

Comment: @MSalters It's undefined behavior, but in so far as the overload contains a user defined type, it will almost certainly work.  In fact, one wonders _why_ it is undefined behavior, since explicit specialization of a template in `std` is allowed.  (Perhaps because there's no way to create an explicit specialization without putting it in `std::`, where as you can overload in any namespace.)